# Proof that a given (equivalence) relation is not a congruence

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

Given the following relation: $$R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mid \exists k,l \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}: x^k = y^l\}$$
it's quite easy to prove that this relation is an equivalence relation, which isn't the problem. But how do I prove that this relation is **not a congruence relation** to the semigroup $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$?

Comment: Well $a \equiv a^l$ and $b \equiv b^k$ does it follow that $ab \equiv a^lb^k$?  More specifically $2 \equiv 4$ and $3 \equiv 27$ but $6 \not \equiv 4*27$ because $(4*27)^k=6^{2k}*3^k=6^{2k}6^{k*\log_3 6} = 6^{n} \implies n =k(2 + \log_3 6)=k(2 + 1 + \log_3 2)$ which is impossible as $\log_3 2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that we of course require $x$ and $y$ to have the same set of prime factors in order to have $R(x,y)$. That, however, isn't sufficient- we also need that $x$ and $y$ have their prime factors in the same ratio. That is, if $p_1, p_2...p_n$ are the prime factors of $x$ and $y$ (these are all of their prime factors, and each of them has multiplicity at least $1$ in both $x$ and $y$), and $m_1,m_2...m_n$ represents the multiplicities of these factors in $x$, and $w_1,w_2...w_n$ represents the multiplicities of these factors in $y$, then $(m_1,m_2...m_n) = c(w_1,w_2...w_n)$ for some nonzero $c$, i.e. they're scalar multiples of each other. In other words, one is a power of the other. (Obviously, zero relates only to itself.)

For this to be a congruence relation, you would need that if $R(x,y)$ and $R(w,z)$ for any integers $w,x,y,z$, then $R(rx,wy)$. Can you then conclude why there would be a problem? Note that $R(x,x)$ is always true.

EDIT: The necessity of both conditions should of course be proven. The second condition can also easily be shown to be sufficient.

Comment: After think a bit about this, it makes totally sense. If you take , for example the tuple (3, 5) and would test it for R(zx,zy), it would already fail on z=2 because the prime factors are different, right?

Comment: Well, no. It's true that $\neg R(6,10)$ because any power of $6$ will have a factor of $3$, while no power of $10$ will have a factor of $3$, but the problem is that $R(3,5)$ is also false. You want to give a pair $(x,y)$ and integer $z$ such that $R(x,y)$ is true, but $R(zx,zy)$ is false.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Missed that it should also fulfill $R(x,y)$ My fault. Do you have an example pair for this on hand?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that any $(x,y)$ pair that satisfies $R(x,y)$ and $x\neq y$, and any integer besides $0$ or $1$ should suffice. Also, somehow this slipped my mind, but the necessary condition means that one is a power of the other. So $R(3,9)$ because $3^2=9$, but $\neg R(6,18)$ because any power of $6$ will have as many factors of $2$ as it does of $3$, but any power of $18$ will have half as many factors of $2$ as it does of $3$.

Comment: I made a slight error in this, though it doesn't effect the proof- you want a pair $(x,y)$ such that $R(x,y)$ and a pair $(w,z)$ such that $R(w,z)$ and $\neg R(xw,yz)$. Of course, you can always consider the second pair to be $(z,z)$ so this holds, but it's still a poor mistake on my part. Apologies.